# How to make CollapsingToolbarLayout stretching

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I used CollapsingToolbarLayout and i need to make it stretching something like this:

[image]

this is my layout:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:title="@string/app_name">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverIv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and i need to make the stretching on the imageView.
there is any way to do it with CollapsingToolbarLayout?
or just with a 3rd party library?
I found a way to do it only with 3rd-party [(this)](https://github.com/matrixxun/PullToZoomInListView) but is work with ListView and i have a Recyclerview.
but anyway i need to work with android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayou.

so there is any chance CollapsingToolbarLayout is supported on something like this? if not, has 3rd party like that are working with actionbar?

Thanks for helping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808207/collapsingtoolbarlayout-image-with-zoom go to this link, i think your solution is there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808207/collapsingtoolbarlayout-image-with-zoom go to this link. you might find solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the overscroll distance that is travelled by user once the `NestedScrollView` has reached the top. Then start to expand the `CollapsingToolbar` for some value and scale the image inside for the same value.

Here in my [blog post](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/overscroll-appbarlayout-behavior-e58f1ee2807) I did something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Ive used [this library](https://github.com/dinuscxj/PullZoomRecyclerView) for similar task and it did the trick.

Comment: I check this library but isn't work with CollapsingToolbarLayout or with some toolbar

Answer (score 1):

try this library it Supports pull-down image of RecyclerView

https://github.com/gatsbydhn/PullToZoomInRecyclerView it has similar functionality to the library that you have mentioned. or you can use this one [PullZoomRecyclerView](https://github.com/dinuscxj/PullZoomRecyclerView)

Comment: I check these libraries . is make the bounce animation but they don't work with CollapsingToolbarLayout or with some toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior by extends appbarLayoutBehavior then override onNestedScroll and add the behavior you want.

you can check source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java

look at snapToChildIfNeeded